# Finding all cases where Project A references Project B with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Suppose I have 100 classes in Project A, and 50 of them reference classes in Project B.

Is there a way to ask Roslyn to find a list of all these 50 classes? Or am I forced to load every class in Project B as a symbol and call `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync()`? (filtering the results down to Project A class references only)

Alternatively if it's easier to find all code references within a class (as opposed to just the class itself) this could work too - I'm trying to measure to what extent one project is coupled to another.